# Is it possible to integrate GCP pub/sub SteamingPullFutures with discordpy?

Tags: asynchronous, discord.py, google-cloud-pubsub, concurrent.futures

I'd like to use a pub/sub `StreamingPullFuture` subscription with discordpy to receive instructions for removing users and sending updates to different servers.

Ideally, I would start this function when starting the discordpy server:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} {bot.user.id}')
    await pub_sub_function()
```

I looked at `discord.ext.tasks` but I don't think this use case fits since I'd like to handle irregularly spaced events dynamically.

I wrote this `pub_sub_function()` ([based on the pub/sub python client docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client#google_cloud_pubsub_v1_subscriber_client_Client_subscribe)) but it doesn't seem to be listening to pub/sub or return anything:

```
def pub_sub_function():

    subscriber_client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

    # existing subscription
    subscription = subscriber_client.subscription_path(
        'my-project-id', 'my-subscription')

    def callback(message):
        print(f"pubsub_message: {message}")
        message.ack()
        return message

    future = subscriber_client.subscribe(subscription, callback)
    try:
        future.result()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.
```

Has anyone done something like this? Is there a standard approach for sending data/messages from external services to a discordpy server and listening asynchronously?

**Update**: I got rid of `pub_sub_function()` and changed the code to this:

```
subscriber_client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

# existing subscription
subscription = subscriber_client.subscription_path('my-project-id', 'my-subscription')

def callback(message):
    print(f"pubsub_message: {message}")
    message.ack()
    return message

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} {bot.user.id}')
    await subscriber_client.subscribe(subscription, callback).result()
```

This works, sort of, but now the `await subscriber_client.subscribe(subscription, callback).result()` is blocking the discord bot, and returning this error:

```
WARNING  discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this [Github pr](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6201#issuecomment-559153445) was very helpful.

In it, the user says that modifications are needed to make it work with asyncio because of Google's pseudo-future implementation:

> Google implemented a custom, psuedo-future
> need monkey patch for it to work with asyncio

But basically, to make the pub/sub future act like the concurrent.futures.Future, the discord.py implementation should be something like this:

```
async def pub_sub_function():
    subscriber_client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    # existing subscription
    subscription = subscriber_client.subscription_path('my-project-id', 'my-subscription')

    def callback(message):
        print(f"pubsub_message: {message}")
        message.ack()
        return message

    future = subscriber_client.subscribe(subscription, callback)
    # Fix the google pseduo future to behave like a concurrent Future:
    future._asyncio_future_blocking = True
    future.__class__._asyncio_future_blocking = True
    real_pubsub_future = asyncio.wrap_future(future)
    return real_pubsub_future
```

and then you need to await the function like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} {bot.user.id}')
    await pub_sub_function()
```

Comment: I tried this and it works but I can't access ```discord.ext.commands.Bot``` from inside the function ```callback```. Returns ```RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task``` even when wrapping it with ```asyncio.run``` like ```asyncio.run(bot.fetch_user('some_user#1234'))```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call some function in the bot loop use **asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(some_function() , client.loop)** instead of asyncio.run(some_function()) in callback(message):

```py
def callback(message):
    print(f"pubsub_message: {message}")
    message.ack()
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(some_function() , client.loop)
    return message
```